# Using storyboard to change view after condition in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, mobile

I am developing iPhone app. I would like to use storyboard for views switching, but I have condition and I would like to do changing after condition is satisfied. How can I do that using storyboard?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What kind of condition is it?

Comment: Whilst your question is a little vague, I have to ask... Are you referring to how do you pass control to another view from the main view (First Responder)? Have you considered using a NavigationViewController? Alternatively if you are simply passing from one view to another via a button, then you might just want to perform a modal operation to the secondary view.

Comment: I am just changing from one view to another on a button click. If label length is 10 than I would like to change the page.

Comment: if someone ever need this: modal works with button and push works only with navigation bar...

Comment: that's also what ross_t said..thanks ross

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using segues.

First, you set up a segue like this, inside storyboard:

[image: first screenshot]

Then, you edit the identifier of the segue to something, in this case, `NextView`:

[image]

Then, finally, in your ViewController, when you want to switch views, call this code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextView" sender:self];
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said. First created a segue from first view container to the second view controller. And I set segue name as you said and after that I added your code on button click. And it still doesn't work. 
I can see in the first view controller that segue is created between two views controller. But when I click on the button I logged message and see it executes. but view doesn't change...

Comment: @boban0987 sorry, push only works when you have a UINavigationController. Try using modal segue with a transition style instead.

Comment: oh, thanks man! it works great with modal. I have no idea what is the difference between modal and push. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Solved my problem a +1 for that, THANKS :-)

Comment: I HAVE problem that after giving segue between viewcontrollers then..i write above code...but due to outlet connection between viewcontrollers ..it bypass my condition..and what is thje result is view changes any solution??